# PDO não conecta ao MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão com o banco por PDO, mas toda vez que tento fazer essa conexão, aparece a mensagem:

```
could not find driver
```

Fui atrás pra saber e fiquei sabendo que tinha que habilitar o PDO no php.ini. Ok, fui lá e tirei a ; da onde precisava, mas mesmo assim ainda aparece a mensagem.

Meu código é esse:

```
<?php

try{
// Faz conexão com banco de daddos
$pdo = new PDO("
    mysql:host=localhost;
    dbname=servidores;", 
    "root", 
    "root");
}catch(PDOException $e){
// Caso ocorra algum erro na conexão com o banco, exibe a mensagem
echo 'Falha ao conectar no banco de dados: '.$e->getMessage();
die;
}

?>
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Você reiniciou o PHP depois de alterar o `php.ini`? Que sistema operacional está usando?

Comment: @user2154508  Qual versão do php vc esta usando? e qual linha foi descomentada?

Comment: Qual sistema operacional você está usando?

Comment: Eu estou usando o Windows, e a versão do meu PHP é: PHP Version 5.2.6

Comment: Cara, tem certeza que está usando PHP 5.2.6? Se sim, tem algum motivo especial? Caso contrário, atualize isso. Não é a resposta direta para seu problema, mas essa versão de é arcaica.

Comment: Olá, podes dizer qual é o erro retornado ?

Comment: @Edilson está no começo da pergunta: `could not find driver`

Comment: @user2154508 além da linha do pdo_mysql você configurou a pasta de extensões do php no arquivo .ini ?

Answer (score 2):

A extensão do `mysql` não está instalada ou você não tem o `mysql` instalado no `localhost`.

Crie um arquivo `info.php` na raiz do webserver, com a funcao `phpinfo();` e depois acesse `localhost/info.php` e procure por `pdo`, la você vê se o driver `pdo` para `mysql` está instalado.

Comment: Isso deveria ser um comentário, não uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

No linux,digite no terminal:

```
php -i | grep drivers
```

E verifique se o driver está habilitado. 
Nos sistemas baseados em Debian/Ubuntu a instalação é simples, no terminal digite:

```
//para instalar
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql

//reiniciando o apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

É bastante comum ocorrer, principalmente com pessoas que desenvolvem em ambiente Windows em versões anteriores à 5.3, versão na qual não existe a necessidade de se habilitar uma extensão à parte para a PDO em si, de elas habilitarem **apenas** a DLL da PDO (php_pdo.dll) e se esquecerem de habilitar a(s) DLL(s) do(s) SGBD(s) suportados pela PDO que estarão utilizando.

A solução, também simples, é editar o PHP.INI removendo o sinal de comentário ( ; ) da linha referente a, no caso, **php_pdo_mysql.dll**

Answer (score 1):

Quando ocorre esse tipo de problema o que pode acontecer:

- se você estiver usando o windows. pode não ter a dll respectiva
- A porta do MySql instalado não é a padrão (3306)
- Os dados do banco de dados não estão corretos

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira rapida e facil de testar se o mySQL está disponivel é pelo proprio PDO com sua função [PDO::getAvailableDrivers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php)

```
  $drivers = PDO::getAvailableDrivers();
    foreach ($drivers as $nome) {
      echo 'Disponivel: ' . $nome . '<br />';
    }
```

Deste modo você lista todos os drivers que o PDO consegue utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `php -m` no terminal/prompt e verifique se a extensão pdo_mysql está realmente habilitada, caso esteja e ainda não funciona verifique se o MySQL foi iniciado.

Comment: Isso deveria ser um comentário, não uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Assim funciona.

```
try{
    // Faz conexão com banco de daddos
    $host = ('localhost');
    $user = ('root');
    $pass = ('root');
    $bancodb = ('curso_php');

    $conecta = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$bancodb", $user, $pass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    // Caso ocorra algum erro na conexão com o banco, exibe a mensagem
    echo 'Falha ao conectar no banco de dados: '.$e->getMessage();
    die;
}
```